# Dynamically changing the iFrame src on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically change the src of the iframe depending on the selection made on the dropdown list. I ran in to error saying unsafe url usage so I added Dom Sanitizer like below

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
   Reports
  </h1>
  </div>
<select (onclick) = "selectedOption($event)">
  <option value="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=401c&autoAuth=true&ctid=5bd1">Productivity</option>
</select>

<iframe width="1140" height="541.25" src="{{safeUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

The typescript is like below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'PowerBIIntegration';
selectedValue: string = ''; 

  selectedOption( event : any){
    this.selectedValue = event.target.value;
    let safeUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.selectedValue);
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  }
}
```

I added `import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';` into the app.module.ts. But it errors out saying

`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(4,21): error TS1005: ',' expected.`
`src/app/app.component.ts(4,30): error TS1005: ',' expected.`
`src/app/app.component.ts(4,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.`

`i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.`

`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(4,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'constructor'.`
`src/app/app.component.ts(4,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'private'.`
`src/app/app.component.ts(4,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'sanitizer'.`
`src/app/app.component.ts(18,25): error TS2339: Property 'sanitizer' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.`

[image]

Comment: Move the constructor inside of the class. You may also want to use `(change)` instead of `(onclick)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to lack some understanding of how the angular data-binding should be used, and you have some blatant issues in your Typescript file.

First, the constructor of your class `AppComponent` should be IN said class, not before:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    ...

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    ...
}
```

Second, in your view, if you want to bind the value of `src` to a variable in your typescript, then use `[src]`, like so:

```
<iframe width="1140" height="541.25" [src]="safeUrl" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

The last issue is that you only declare `safeUrl` in the `selectedOption` of your component, it's not a member variable of the component itself, so the view cannot access it, you should change your component like so:

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'PowerBIIntegration';
    selectedValue: string = '';
    safeUrl: string;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    selectedOption(event : any) {
        this.selectedValue = event.target.value;
        this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: iframe src did not change after selectedOption

Comment: I am new to Angular and type scripting. Thank you for the help, one more issue with the SafeHtml type. `error TS2322: Type 'SafeHtml' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: You probably have to use this method instead: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl and change the type of `safeUrl` in the component to `SafeUrl`.

Comment: The issue is I am seeing the response like shown in the question

Comment: I imagine this is because at the start when the page starts, nothing is selected. Add a `*ngIf="safeUrl"` on the iframe, to only show it once an option has been selected.

Comment: Still  The page keeps loading throwing the error.`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'safeUrl'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'safeUrl'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)`

Comment: You have to update your code, this error doesn't make sense based on what you provided here. Also make sure that `safeUrl` has the expected value.

Comment: Like AntoineB said, for the different types of url you need to chose the correct method.
For me it only worked with this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl